# SimpleDateFormat behaves differently on different tablet

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I have an Asus Fonepad first generation(android 4.1.2) and an Asus Fonepad second generation(android 4.3).

I use the following code to parse the date to the desired format in my app:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", /*new Locale("nl", "NL")*/Locale.GERMANY);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(/*"Europe/Amsterdam"*/"Europe/Berlin"));
        String time = df.format(new Date());
```

The above code results in "Dez 23 17:09:25 2013" on the first generation fonepad and "Dez. 23 17:09:25 2013" on the second generation fonepad.

As you can see, the second generation adds a dot after the month.

this causes a parsexception on the server side.

Why does SimpleDateFormat behave differently on different devices(android versions)? This is worrying.

Is there a way to always get the same format? What is the solution to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

SimpleDateFormat (and some other framework classes) use icu4c library to format content. Month format for DE was changed between 49.2 and 50.1 versions of this library.
No, you can't expect same behavior for all android versions.

Link to sources: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu4c/+/android-4.4.2_r1/data/locales/de.txt

Add: If you sending data to a server than solution is to use only numbers: 12 will be always 12 for December.